# what is php-fpm warning "failed to acquire scoreboard"?

Tags: php

what is php-fpm warning "failed to acquire scoreboard" in fpm error log?

```
tail -f /var/log/php-fpm.log
[08-Oct-2014 03:36:36] WARNING: failed to acquire scoreboard
[08-Oct-2014 03:40:39] WARNING: failed to acquire scoreboard
[08-Oct-2014 03:42:54] WARNING: failed to acquire scoreboard
[08-Oct-2014 03:47:01] WARNING: failed to acquire scoreboard
```

use-case:

php version 5.4.25

php-fpm instance say 'pf-9000' is connecting to 2nd php-fpm instance say 'pf-9005' with fastcgi protocol on same server.
The error is visible on both php-fpm instances.

Request flow:

```
web client -> nginx -> pf-9000 -> pf-9005
```

Response flow:

```
pf-9005 -> pf-9000 -> nginx -> web client
```

Answer (score 0):

A scoreboard is a structure that holds the state of the FPM pool and its worker threads. It's created in shared memory, and if that memory can't be allocated, [an error is logged](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_request.c#L46).